# Reading from TCP device object

Tags: c, winapi, tcp, driver

I'm trying to open a handle to the TCP object device driver.

This is my code:

```
NTSTATUS OpenTcpDeviceObject(PHANDLE tcpFile, ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess) {
    UNICODE_STRING fileName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IOBlock;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&fileName, TEXT("\\Device\\Tcp"));

    InitializeObjectAttributes(
        &objectAttributes, &fileName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

    NTSTATUS Status = NtOpenFile(
        tcpFile, DesiredAccess | SYNCHRONIZE, &objectAttributes, &IOBlock,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        *tcpFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    return Status;
}
```

However Status returns `-1073741790`, the question is why is this not working? I'm running this from usermode, on a non-administrator account. From my understanding, this operation doesn't require admin privileges as long as I have the `ACCESS_MASK` set to `FILE_READ_DATA`.

**NOTE**

The `Status` that is returned points to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5)` as a Dos Error. But how can access be denied if I only ask for read permissions? However, when I run [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) which accesses the Tcp device object, it allows me to access multicast/unicast addresses without privileges!

So what is the problem?

Comment: @HarryJohnston What do you mean? `SYNCHRONIZE` is usually included with `FILE_READ_DATA` - why would it be the problem?

Comment: There's no rule AFAIK that says you must be granted `SYNCHRONIZE` if you are granted `FILE_READ_DATA` so that *might* have been the problem.  Turns out it wasn't, but it might have been. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *\Device\Tcp* have next *DACL*

```
T FL AcessMsK Sid
A 00 001200A0 S-1-1-0 'Everyone'
A 00 001F01FF S-1-5-18 'SYSTEM'
A 00 001F01FF S-1-5-32-544 'Administrators'
A 00 001200A0 S-1-5-12 'RESTRICTED'
```

if you not *`SYSTEM`* or *`Administrators`* yo have only `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_EXECUTE|SYNCHRONIZE|READ_CONTROL` or this combination declared as `FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE` in *wdm.h*. so you not have `FILE_READ_DATA` access and must got `c00000022` when you ask for `FILE_READ_DATA`

about `GetAdaptersAddresses` - it not open tcp device with `FILE_READ_DATA`. he ask only `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|SYNCHRONIZE`. you never will be call `ZwReadFile` on tcp device. we got info from it via `ZwDeviceIoControlFile`. required access is encoded in every *IOCTL* code and most *IOCTL* codes declared as `FILE_ANY_ACCESS` - this mean that file handle with **any** access is ok. for example `IOCTL_TCP_QUERY_INFORMATION_EX` defined as `CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_NETWORK, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)` - so you not need read data access to file. open file with `SYNCHRONIZE` access only - this will be enough.

and as note `GetAdaptersAddresses` use *\Device\Nsi* on latest windows versions